# Docx4j, JAXB in eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jaxb, docx4j

sorry for bad english)

I trying to create eclipse plugin, which generating some docx-files.
I downloaded **docx4j** (binary jar 3.2.1), include all dependecies and jars into plugin project.

NO MAVEN!

After that, I tried next:

```
try {
        WordprocessingMLPackage wmlPack = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code placed in plugin popupMenu action. He called properly. But this code failed. This logs:

```
DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils .getResource line 70 - Attempting to load: docx4j.properties
INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context .<clinit> line 74 - java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context .<clinit> line 75 - java.version=1.7.0_71
DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils .getResource line 70 - Attempting to load: org/docx4j/wml/jaxb.properties
DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils .getResource line 82 - Not using MOXy, since no resource: org/docx4j/wml/jaxb.properties
INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context .<clinit> line 98 - No MOXy JAXB config found; assume not intended..
INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils .getPrefixMapper line 60 - Using NamespacePrefixMapperSunInternal, which is suitable for Java 6
INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context .<clinit> line 107 - Using Java 6/7 JAXB implementation
```

and

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-04-29 09:44:24.538
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
Error while logging event loop exception:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.util 4 0 2015-04-29 09:44:55.114
!MESSAGE Unable to create more threads!
Active Thread Pool tasks: 0
Exception in thread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" Exception in thread "Worker-0"
```

Ahh, I see, error somewhere in docx4j.jaxb.Context class. I downloaded sources from ([GitHub](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j)) added some custom logging and builded it.
I found out: Error sit in method **javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance()** (org.docx4j.jaxb.Context, line 132).

I tried next code directly in plugin code:

```
try {
            JAXBContext.newInstance("org.docx4j.wml:org.docx4j.w14:org.docx4j.w15:" +
                    "org.docx4j.schemas.microsoft.com.office.word_2006.wordml:" +
                    "org.docx4j.dml:org.docx4j.dml.chart:org.docx4j.dml.chartDrawing:org.docx4j.dml.compatibility:org.docx4j.dml.diagram:org.docx4j.dml.lockedCanvas:org.docx4j.dml.picture:org.docx4j.dml.wordprocessingDrawing:org.docx4j.dml.spreadsheetdrawing:org.docx4j.dml.diagram2008:" +
                    // All VML stuff is here, since compiling it requires WML and DML (and MathML), but not PML or SML
                    "org.docx4j.vml:org.docx4j.vml.officedrawing:org.docx4j.vml.wordprocessingDrawing:org.docx4j.vml.presentationDrawing:org.docx4j.vml.spreadsheetDrawing:org.docx4j.vml.root:" +
                    "org.docx4j.docProps.coverPageProps:" +
                    "org.opendope.xpaths:org.opendope.conditions:org.opendope.questions:org.opendope.answers:org.opendope.components:org.opendope.SmartArt.dataHierarchy:" +
                    "org.docx4j.math:" +
                    "org.docx4j.sharedtypes:org.docx4j.bibliography");
        } catch (JAXBException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But this error don't print stacktrace. Just "Unhandled event loop exception". And my CPU loaded on 60%. That's all, what I can see.

```
My configuration:
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -data C:\Users\{My username hehe}\workspace/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev file:C:/Users/{And here my username too}/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog
```

Thank you for your attention!)

Comment: I don't see any docx4j error in what you've posted.  "Unhandled event loop exception" isn't a docx4j error; You'll have to research what that means in eclipse